# NoMethodError using active admin rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form(address) nested in another form (customer). I am creating a customer in my app and when i click creates, it creates the customer in the database but when it routes to the show page, I get this error.

first and foremost here is the error

```
NoMethodError in Admin/customers#show

Showing /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-fa7e4de2d5fa/app/views/active_admin/resource/show.html.arb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `address' for #<Customer:0x007ffb5619f420>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: insert_tag renderer_for(:show)
Rails.root: /Users/danielhatcher/rails/printonrails

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/admin/customers.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"11"}
```

here is my controller

```
ActiveAdmin.register Customer do
    # Menu item
  menu :label => "Customers", :parent => "Administration"

  filter :name, label: "by Name"
  filter :company, label: "by Company"
  filter :email, label: "by Email"
  filter :phone, label: "by Phone Number"

  index do
    column :name
    column :company
    column :email
    column :phone
  end

    form :partial => "form"

  show :title => :name do

    panel "Customer Details" do
          attributes_table_for resource do
            row :name
            row :company
            row :email
            row :phone
          end
      end
      text_node(render :partial => "admin/addresses/form", :locals => { :address => resource.address })
    end
end
```

here is my form

```
<%=
form.has_many :addresses do |address| 
address.inputs "Address" do 

    address.inputs :class => "" do 
      address.input :street 
      address.input :city 
      address.input :state
      address.input :zip
    end 
  end 
end 
%>
```

Customer Model

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :email, :phone, :addresses_attributes, :company
  has_many :addresses
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

address model

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :street, :city, :state, :zip, :customer_id
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

I am not sure why text node is triggering this error and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your customer model have an address method?

Comment: the customer has_many addresses

Comment: So there won't be a method called `address`, which you attempt to call.

Comment: I am still not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Pass in `addresses`, not `address`?

Comment: Define "did not work."

Comment: I got the same error when i changed :address to :addresses.

Comment: Edited my question with all models associated